# Capturing just a part of the website

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regular expression like this;

**`/(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)/`**

I just want to capture the domain part of any website disregard to the protocol. So, this regular expression works, but it also captures some empty spaces. Where does the empty space here come from ? If I understand this, it could be very helpful to me.

If I feed the following strings to match,

Inputs:

```
http://google.com
https://www.simplecms.com
www.facebook.com
gmail.com
```

Outputs:

```
Match 1
1.  google.com
Match 2
1.   
Match 3
1.  simplecms.com
Match 4
1.   
Match 5
1.  facebook.com
Match 6
1.   
Match 7
1.  gmail.com
Match 8
1.   
Match 9
1.
```

If you look at the output, it does the job but it also captures some empty string. I am sure there is some better way to capture this thing.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regular expression?

Comment: What do you mean ? I want to learn or I have some task where I need to capture the part of the string. Do you have any better suggestion, please you are welcome. Thanks

Comment: These days, any language that is out of its infancy and has a passing relationship with the web, should have tools pre-built to deal with the internet and URIs. Reuse those, and don't try to reinvent the wheels. An hour spent researching can save you days and days of writing and debugging. If you can't find anything suitable after that research THEN write something using well-tested regex patterns. There are multiple sources available for those patterns so, again, you don't have to reinvent or even modify them. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18619388/128421) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a start/end of line to the beginning and end of the regex.  `^` at the beginning `$` at the end, matches on the line.  I think what was happening is your regex was seeing the returns and matching those.

Try: `^(?:http[s]?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*)$`  (NOTE: you may have to escape things depending on the language).

Using your example you provided I set up a [quick test to show the matches here](http://rubular.com/r/f7pQKhXNOL).

Comment: That is exactly what had happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can go with this non-regex approach :-

```
require 'uri'

str = <<-eot
http://google.com
https://www.simplecms.com
www.facebook.com
gmail.com
eot

str.split.map{|u| uri=URI(u); uri.scheme ? uri.host : u}
# => ["google.com", "www.simplecms.com", "www.facebook.com", "gmail.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to recreate the pattern used to parse URLs.

Here's a quick and dirty list of the patterns available to you using Ruby's [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class. You shouldn't need to access these directly, because there are methods that provide the needed logic to handle cases that patterns can't handle.

The actual definitions are in URI's [common.rb](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/uri/common.rb):

```
require 'uri'

URI::REGEXP::PATTERN.constants.each do |s|
  puts ':%s => %%r/%s/x' % [s, URI::REGEXP::PATTERN.const_get(s)]
end
```

Which outputs:

```
:ALPHA => %r/a-zA-Z/x
:ALNUM => %r/a-zA-Z\d/x
:HEX => %r/a-fA-F\d/x
:ESCAPED => %r/%[a-fA-F\d]{2}/x
:UNRESERVED => %r/\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d/x
:RESERVED => %r/;/?:@&=+$,\[\]/x
:DOMLABEL => %r/(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:[-a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d])?)/x
:TOPLABEL => %r/(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[-a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d])?)/x
:HOSTNAME => %r/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z\d](?:[-a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.)*(?:[a-zA-Z](?:[-a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z\d])?)\.?/x
:URIC => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})/x
:URIC_NO_SLASH => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})/x
:QUERY => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*/x
:FRAGMENT => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*/x
:IPV4ADDR => %r/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/x
:IPV6ADDR => %r/(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)/x
:IPV6REF => %r/\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\]/x
:HOST => %r/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])/x
:HOSTPORT => %r/(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?/x
:USERINFO => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*/x
:PATH_SEGMENTS => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*/x
:REG_NAME => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+/x
:REL_SEGMENT => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+/x
:SCHEME => %r/[a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*/x
:ABS_PATH => %r//(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*/x
:REL_PATH => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?/x
:NET_PATH => %r///(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?/x
:HIER_PART => %r/(?://(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)(?:\?(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?/x
:OPAQUE_PART => %r/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*/x
:ABS_URI => %r/[a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*:(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)(?:\?(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)/x
:REL_URI => %r/(?://(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?)(?:\?(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)?/x
:URI_REF => %r/(?:[a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*:(?:(?://(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)(?:\?(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)|(?://(?:(?:(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*@)?(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\])(?::\d*)?|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?|/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*|(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?)(?:\?(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)?)?(?:#(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)?/x
:X_ABS_URI => %r/
        ([a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*):                           (?# 1: scheme)
        (?:
           ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)                    (?# 2: opaque)
        |
           (?:(?:
             //(?:
                 (?:(?:((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)@)?        (?# 3: userinfo)
                   (?:((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\]))(?::(\d*))?))? (?# 4: host, 5: port)
               |
                 ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)                 (?# 6: registry)
               )
             |
             (?!//))                           (?# XXX: '//' is the mark for hostport)
             (/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?                    (?# 7: path)
           )(?:\?((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                 (?# 8: query)
        )
        (?:\#((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                  (?# 9: fragment)
      /x
:X_REL_URI => %r/
        (?:
          (?:
            //
            (?:
              (?:((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)@)?       (?# 1: userinfo)
                ((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\]))?(?::(\d*))?  (?# 2: host, 3: port)
            |
              ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)             (?# 4: registry)
            )
          )
        |
          ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)              (?# 5: rel_segment)
        )?
        (/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?                  (?# 6: abs_path)
        (?:\?((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?              (?# 7: query)
        (?:\#((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?           (?# 8: fragment)
      /x
```

URI expects a string to begin with some sort of scheme. When you know the host is a web site, you can fool it by prepending the "http://", or just use the host as is. If there is more to the string being passed in than just the host, prepend "http://" and let URI peel apart the segments of the string:

```
require 'uri'

hosts = %w[
  http://google.com
  https://www.simplecms.com
  www.facebook.com
  gmail.com
  http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413
  https://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413
  foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413
  ].map { |url|

    scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = case !!url[%r(\Ahttps?://)i]
    when true
      URI.split(url)
    when false
      URI.split("http://#{ url }")
    end

    host
  }
hosts # => ["google.com", "www.simplecms.com", "www.facebook.com", "gmail.com", "foo.com", "foo.com", "foo.com"]
```

You can also access the host component directly:

```
url = "http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413"
uri = URI(url)
uri.host # => "foo.com"

scheme, userinfo, host, port, registry, path, opaque, query, fragment = URI.split("http://#{ url }") 
scheme # => "http"
userinfo # => nil
host # => "http"
port # => ""
registry # => nil
path # => "//foo.com/posts"
opaque # => nil
query # => "id=30&limit=5"
fragment # => "time=1305298413"
```

The above caveat about URI wanting to see a scheme still applies.

URI is "FTW" because it can take apart the string, and allow you to access each of the components. It also lets you build or modify the URI and do so in an RFC-compliant way.

If URI isn't sophisticated enough, there's also [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable), which is even more FTW.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach that works with your use cases:

```
> sites
 => ["http://google.com", "https://www.simplecms.com", "www.facebook.com", "gmail.com"] 
> sites.map{|s| s.split('/').last}
 => ["google.com", "www.simplecms.com", "www.facebook.com", "gmail.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression just use the builtin [URI parser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'uri'

def get_domain(url)
  url = 'http://' + url unless url =~ /^https?:\/\//i
  begin
    URI.parse(url).host
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    nil
  end
end

get_domain('http://google.com')         # => google.com
get_domain('https://www.simplecms.com') # => www.simplecms.com
get_domain('www.facebook.com')          # => www.facebook.com
get_domain('gmail.com')                 # => gmail.com
```